# how to get amout of ticks for a reference date on the iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm programming against a Webservice that requires the amount of ticks (for the current time) (A single tick represents one hundred nanoseconds or one ten-millionth of a second) since 1.1.0001 (midnight).

what is the easiest way to get the amount of ticks from an NSDate Object?

thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make 1.1.0001 into an NSDate and then use the NSDate method timeIntervalSinceNow and multiply by 10 million.

Answer (score 0):

This code will give you GMT time.

```
const long long UNIX_EPOCH_IN_CLR_TICKS = 621355968000000000 ;
long long time = UNIX_EPOCH_IN_CLR_TICKS + [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970] * pow(10, 7);
```